# Displaying information in an Azure DevOps pipeline summary

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Azure DeVops pipelines to run my integration tests.  The test results are used to generate a report that is copied over to a static site (AWS S3).  Each URL for each test run is unique and I am looking for some kind of way to make it easy to get to that URL so the report can be viewed.

Right now I am just using an echo to spit the URL out to the log for the particular agent task that copies out the report, I'd like to figure out some way to make it easier to get to that URL.

Is it possible to add information to the summary screen?
[devops pipeline summary screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoHCv.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to your description,  you could create a real custom summary tab to display customized info.

To achieve this, you need to write an extension by [Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk).

MS team has provided a great sample on github [Build Results Enhancer](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer), you can check this sample for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  that sounds like a good solution, so I will look in to that.